# Tail Call Elimination in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, scheme, tail-recursion, tail-call-optimization

Can somebody rewrite this (plt) Scheme code into Clojure?

```
(define (f n)
   (printf "(f ~a)~n" n)
   (g n))

(define (g n)
   (printf "(g ~a)~n" n)
   (h n))

(define (h n)
   (printf "(h ~a)~n" n)
   (f (+ n 1)))
```

In such a way as to not collapse the procedures f, g, and h together and to allow the code to run indefinitely without crashing?

Answer (score 30):

Use a trampoline:

```
(declare f)

(defn h [n]
   (println "(h " n ")")
   #(f (+ n 1)))

(defn g [n]
   (println "(g " n ")")
   #(h n))

(defn f [n]
   (println "(f " n ")")
   #(g n))
```

Kick it off with:

```
(trampoline f 0)
```

I've had this code running on my pc in the background for about 5 hours now and the memory usage is flat.